# Handling cookies in HTTP request in Jmeter

Tags: apache, xmlhttprequest, jmeter, load, restful-url

I have a Jmeter load project the requires retrieving 2 values of cookies and resend them in the other requests.

Here is my project test plan:

```
-Test Plan
-Thread Group
-Login request
-Payment page
-Payment history page
-HTTP Cookie Manager
-HTTP Header Manager
-View Results Tree
```

Cookie Data:
JSESSIONID=0000SZb55xyLAaqLlDzumq_PpIw:-1; XSRF-TOKEN=a684e233-648e-4219-ae21-25fb362e232d

The cookie data is received successfully from the login request by cookie manager and sent in the second request (Payment page) but in the third request (Payment history page) only JSESSIONID is sent and I don't know why the second cookie is not sent in the third request.

Comment: See https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites

Comment: I tried this solution but the same behavior is still exist

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are not getting this cookie in [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header for second request therefore it doesn't get picked up by the cookie manager. If your application expects the cookie in 3rd request it might be your application issue.

As a workaround you can store the cookie value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for later re-use.

- Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
      CookieManager.save.cookies=true
- Restart JMeter to pick the property up
- That's it, now you should be able to refer cookie value as `${COOKIE_XSRF-TOKEN}` where required, for example add another [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) as a child of the 3rd request (according to [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) "local" cookie manager will override the "global" one) and define `XSRF_TOKEN` and other cookies if needed there)

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more information on handling cookies in JMeter tests.

Comment: I did the same as you described and added a local cookie manager to the second request but still the same problem